# How to show notification on lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to show a textview object on the lockscreen. I was looking around for some help but could not find an good sources. Can someone help me out on how I can display a textview object on the lockscreen?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, yourMessage);
```

Comment: I saw this. Can the message be a View object? or does this message have to be a string?

Comment: @AndroidLove I think the only way to do that is by creating your own lockscreen widget

Comment: its working fine but can we get the same as like facebook notification appears while lock screen ?